# Restructing webpage using RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to reorganize my webpage so that instead of having 40 files for each page, I am just using 1 file that is redirected via rewriterule.
In my directory I have files such as:

1.php

2.php

3.php

about.php

help.php

What I am trying to accomplish is if the file exists, just deliver it like normal (about.php, help.php). If it doesn't exist anymore though, then grab the page and load it dynamically.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?link=$1 [L]
```

Then on page.php I have:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/'.$_GET['link'].'.php');
```

The issue I'm running into is it is pulling everything. Which will give the error:

```
include(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/files/1.php.php'
```

Since it has the double .php on the end. I can alter the file there, but then all my new links will be broken since they don't use the extensions anymore.
Surely it can't be an 'either all extension' or 'no extensions' situation?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if `$_GET['link']` contains a `.` and you know it's a file with extension then explode on that and just use the first part. Otherwise use it as is.

```
if (strpos($_GET['link'], ".") !== false) {
    $parts = explode(".",$_GET['link']);
    $link = $parts[0];
}else{
    $link = $_GET['link'];
}

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/'.$link.'.php');
```